# Android-Manifest 'android:icon' is not a string value

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-manifest, google-play-console

When I try to upload my APK to the Google Play Store Console, it says that the 'android:icon' value in Android Manifest is not a string value. But if I take away the sting quotes, it gives me another error. How do I fix this?.

I have tried taking away the string quotes, but when I do, it gives me another error

android:icon="@android:color/background_dark"

NOTE: I am using android studio

Comment: you can't use color as icon

Comment: you want to create a colored icon default android icon(don't do this btw), what you're doing is trying to set a string as an icon(which is obviously incorrect logic)

Comment: You need to reference an actual image in your resources, not a color definition.

Comment: Have you solved this? Try accepting one of the answers!

Answer (score 2):

You have to mention the path for the image you want to display which can be fetched from the drawable or mipmap package of the res package

android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"

or android:icon="@drawable/app_logo"

Comment: I tried the mipmap option... It still gives me the same error. Do I need to take away the quotes?

Comment: no need to take away the quotes they are to be kept, your mipmap icon is it a proper image or not else drawable also works well for the icon.

Answer (score 0):

Icon values of these attributes should be localized and therefore set from a resource or theme. Resource values are expressed in the following format,

```
@[package:]type:name
```

where the package name can be omitted if the resource is in the same package as the application, type is a type of resource — such as "string" or "drawable" — and name is the name that identifies the specific resource.

For example:

```
<activity android:icon="@drawable/smallPic" . . . >
```

Values from a theme are expressed in a similar manner, but with an initial '?' rather than '@':

```
?[package:]type:name
```

String values
Where an attribute value is a string, double backslashes ('\') must be used to escape characters — for example, '\n' for a newline or '\uxxxx' for a Unicode character.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use simple colors for icons,  you have to specify a icon drawable,

You have to specify it like this:

```
android:icon = "@folder/icon"
```

For example, if your folder is `drawable` and the name of the icon is `logo`, then your attribute should be like this:

```
android:icon = "@drawable/logo"
```